# how to remove the blank space in this figure in order to use any size (width=.. \textwith, height=...\textheight)

Tags: tcolorbox, includegraphics

i want to include image with a specific size inside the box in my document, [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} % Article sur papier A4 en 11 pt
\usepackage{graphicx}                 % Pour afficher des fichiers images
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{concil}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}           % Document en français
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[skins,breakable,xparse]{tcolorbox}%
\begin{document} 

\section{Applications}
Soient $(\zeta)$ un cercle de centre $O$ et $(AT)$ sa tangente au point $A$, sachant que $\widehat{TAB}=20\si\degree$:

1- Déduire la mesure de l'angle $\widehat{AOB}$ ?

2- Déterminer les mesures de  $\widehat{ABO}$ et $\widehat{OAB}$ ?

 \begin{tcolorbox}[
     enhanced,clip upper,%<------------
     colframe=red,colback=gray,boxrule=2pt,arc=10pt,
     boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, height=0.6\textheight ]{exercice-application}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

when i use this code i get something, like:[image]
**Edit**

I would like to reduce the size of the image in my document, I don't want to take a half-page for a figure if you see it's not professional to give a figure a half-page
as shown in the following image [image]

Comment: It's really difficult to see what you're asking here.  You want a "specific size"; what size?  You've told LaTeX to set your image at half the textwidth, which is exactly what it's done.

Comment: I want to remove the gray side in right in the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've instructed TeX to make your image half of the `\textwidth` when you say `width=0.5\textwidth`; say `width=\textwidth` instead.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} % Article sur papier A4 en 11 pt
\usepackage{graphicx}                 % Pour afficher des fichiers images
\usepackage[skins,breakable,xparse]{tcolorbox}%
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,clip upper,%<------------
    colframe=red,colback=gray,boxrule=2pt,arc=10pt,
    boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=0.6\textheight]{examp.pdf}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

This gets you what you want:

[image: Results]

It's also worth noting that your example, while working, is far from minimal.  Remove all the packages that you don't actually need to get the problem you're having; often they can complicate things, and it might be that it reveals what your problem is before you ask.

EDIT:  Since your concern seems to be shrinking the entire image, including the `tcolorbox`, just give `tcolorbox` a `width` rule:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} % Article sur papier A4 en 11 pt
\usepackage{graphicx}                 % Pour afficher des fichiers images
\usepackage[skins,breakable,xparse]{tcolorbox}%
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.5\textwidth,
    enhanced,clip upper,%<------------
    colframe=red,colback=gray,boxrule=2pt,arc=10pt,
    boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=0.6\textheight]{examp.pdf}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Your image will then be half the width of the page.  If you want it to be centered, surround it with `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`; if you want it to be wrapped by surrounding text, take a look at the `wrapfig` package.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I edit my question to show you the size that I want to reduce in my document

Comment: Your edit doesn't clarify much to me.  You want the figure to be smaller?  Then make your tcolorbox smaller.

Comment: yes, i want to reduce it to be smaller in my document, how can i do that with tcolorbox, thank you

Comment: thank you very much for your help